# What does parentheses mean in typeof in C?

Tags: c, typeof

I am studying the Linux `container_of` function and I find the use of parentheses of typeof is really confusing.

Here is the code of the function `container_of`:

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({ \
    const typeof( ((type*)0)->member) * __mptr =(ptr);\
    (type*)( (char*)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

At the second line, we have

`const typeof( ((type*)0)->member) * __mptr =(ptr);`

I do not understand why we use parentheses on the right side.

I search it online and find some similar usage. For example, from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html , I found a function `max(a,b)`

```
#define max(a,b) 
({ typeof (a) _a = (a); \
  typeof (b) _b = (b); \
  _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
```

In this case, we do have similar usage `typeof (a) _a = (a);`

Why should we use parentheses on the right side? Can we remove the parentheses on the right side to make it `typeof (a) _a = a;`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you! That solves the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros created via `#define` perform direct token substitution.  Because of this, using parenthesis around the arguments of a function-like macro is good practice as it prevents unexpected issues from occurring.

For example:

```
#define multiply(x, y) x * y
```

If you were to use this macro here:

```
int z = multiply(1 + 3, 4 + 5) / 3;
```

You might expect `z` to contain the value 12, but you would be mistaken.

It would expand the above to:

```
int z = 1 + 3 * 4 + 5 / 3;
```

Which would result in 14.  Using parenthesis avoids this issue.  If it was instead defined as:

```
#define multiply(x, y) ((x) * (y))
```

Then the above example would expand to:

```
int z = ((1 + 3) * (4 + 5)) / 3;
```

Which would give the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

We do not know argument will be used for `ptr` when the `container_of` macro is used. It might be an identifier name like `MyPointer`. But it might be an expression, like `MyArray + 3`.

Common practice in macros is to use parentheses around parameters in the replacement list. For example, if we define `square`:

```
#define square(x) ((x) * (x))
```

Then `square(3+4)` will be replaced with `((3+4) * (3+4))`, which is 49 as desired. If we had instead used:

```
#define square(x) (x * x)
```

then `square(3+4)` would be replaced with `(3+4 * 3+4)`, which would be evaluated as `3 + 4*3 + 4`, which is `3 + 12 + 4`, which is 19, which is not desired.

Similarly, in the code you show, `const typeof( ((type*)0)->member) * __mptr =(ptr);`, `ptr` is being used to initialize a newly defined object named `__mptr`. It is in parentheses just for safety. It does not change how the `typeof` operates.

You should not remove these parentheses. In this particular context, there is not much that would normally be passed for `ptr` that would break the macro without the parentheses, but there are some expressions that are theoretically possible that could break it.